Google Spreadsheet IF and ISBLANK condition
I am trying to use IF with ISBLANK condition in Google Spreadsheet and it is constantly showing an unknown error in the formula. I tried various variants of the formula, but it is still not working. All cells are set up as numeric fields.
First I tried with =(IF(ISBLANK(C2),B2,C2)+E3)*(1+H2), but an unknown error shown, so I changed to:
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),(B2+E3)*(1+H2),(C2+E3)*(1+H2))

I even tried:
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),((B2+IF(ISBLANK(E3),"0",E3))*(1+H2),(C2+IF(ISBLANK(E3),"0",E3))*(1+H2)))

As I said, all B, C, E and H columns are set to numeric fields, what is wrong here, please, any ideas?

Sorry, the issue was with the delimiter in the Google Spreadsheet. It has to be ;, not ,. So this one worked: =(IF(ISBLANK(C2);B2;C2)+E3)*(1+H2)

Side note on this one: If your Google Sheets locality setting is under the EU, the formula uses ;. Otherwise, , works just fine.

Check your Country Setting in your Sheet. For EU you have to use ; and not ,
